# Display date difference in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have an CV and would like to automatically update my age when opening. So, what formula should I insert in a **MS Word field**?

Something like `{= {DATE} - {"01/01/1983"} }` ?

Comment: As an aside, this is a big no-no in the UK now... Employment legislation has made it illegal for employers to discriminate on an age basis so ages and DOB on CVs is a thing of the past!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{IF{DATE\@"MM"} >= 01 { = {DATE\@"YYYY"} – 1983 \#"00"} { = {DATE\@"YYYY"} – 1984 \#"00"}}`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible inside a field but very complex. See [this article](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001579_Calculating_Dates_with_Fields.html) and [this article](http://www.addbalance.com/word/faq_supplement.htm#dates) for more info.

The easiest way will be to use a macro.

Comment: I saw similar articles, but... not very clear there. Very complex to obtain difference between 2 dates? :"(

Comment: complex to do in a field code, easy to do in a macro.